# What is the syntax for implicit cast operator in dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to cast instances of my custom class A to int. What is the syntax of the implicit cast operator? (I thought I remembered that there is such a feature but I can't find it on the web)

```
int a = (new A());
```

Comment: I believe the syntax is "no syntax at all". In other words - leave off the `()` and it "should just work". See http://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/types-and-casting-in-dart.html . There has to be an assumption that a downcast is possible (and makes sense). What is your class `A`?

Comment: You can write var a = new A(); int b = a;

Comment: Implicit type conversion hard to implement in script langauge. But explicit conversion can be implemented very easy. Currrently in Dart not exists explicit conversion operator as such. So you cannot do this in Dart `var a = (int) new A()` because explicit conversion operator not implemented in Dart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type annotations are not allowed to affect behavior in Dart.  If you're not running in checked mode, then this:

```dart
int a = new A();
```

will work the same as this:

```dart
var a = new A();
```

at run-time.  In other words, when not in checked mode, you're welcome to store your `A` in a variable annotated as an `int`, but no actual conversion takes place.

If you are running in checked mode, the first form will give you a runtime exception.

I'm not sure, but I *think* what you're asking for is a way to define a conversion between your class `A` and `int` that will happen automatically when "cast" to an `int`.  No such thing exists, to my knowledge.  You should simply define a method to do so.  For example:

```dart
int a = new A().to_i();
```

Answer (score 45):

You can also use `as` to help tell the tools "no, really, treat this object as this type".

A good example of this is when you have to deal with dart:html's `querySelector()` function.

```dart
FormElement form = querySelector('#sign-up') as FormElement;
```

In the above, the object returned by `querySelector('#sign-up')` is checked that it is really an instance of FormElement.

Learn more at https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#operators

Comment: Hi, Jonathan from The Future here. Won't it be a `FormElement` anyway even without the cast since the variable is typed? Of course, this is coming from a post Dart 2.0 world, but even still, isn't the as redundant?

Comment: Also from the future here, it should be pointed out that in Dart 2.0 at least, the `as` keyword is for implicit conversion (type checking) purposes, not for explicit conversions. For example, you could use it to downcast between a parent type and a child type (assuming the type of the object actually can resolve to that child type). It will _not_ work to define custom conversions between what would otherwise be two completely different types as requested by OP. (i.e. `int a = new Foo() as int;` will throw an error unless `Foo` actually inherits from `int`.)